# orbeon dynamic dropdown own list without country list?

Tags: orbeon

Can I add my own dynamic drop down list (15000) rows in orbeon? show me the  video. that is help me a lot can we add any easy way? I drag and drop the form control.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just read this documentation, it isn't so hard. You just need configure this field. https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/static-dynamic-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You do this by:

1. Adding a Dynamic Dropdown to your form.
2. Clicking on the gears icon to open the Control Settings.
3. Enter the URL of your service, choices, label, and value formulas.